# Error message on Teradata: Select failed 9134 : Intermediate aggregate storage limit for aggregation has been exceeded during computation. Help please

Tags: sql, teradata

```
s

elect a.ECCA_MBR_ID, a.INTRCTN_KEY_ID, CRTE_DT, a.LVL3_ACCT_GID, b.LVL1_ACCT_ID, b.LVL2_ACCT_ID, b.LVL1_ACCT_NM,  SYS_ID, INTRCTN_TYP_CD, INTRCTN_RSLT_CD

,TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM (XMLAGG(INTRCTN_NM || ',' order by INTRCTN_NM ) (VARCHAR(750)))) as INTRCTN_NM_LIST, TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM (XMLAGG(INTRCTN_VAL || ',' order by INTRCTN_NM ) (VARCHAR(750)))) as INTRCTN_VAL_LIST

from DWU_EDW.V_ECCA_INTRCTN a

left join DWU_EDW.V_CLNT_ACCT_DENORM b on a.LVL3_ACCT_GID = b.LVL3_ACCT_GID

left join DWU_EDW.V_ECCA_INTRCTN_DAT c on a.INTRCTN_KEY_ID = c.INTRCTN_KEY_ID

where a.INTRCTN_TYP_CD IN ('3217', '8503', '3180', '3286')

and

(

(INTRCTN_NM IN ('COMPONENT_ID', 'IS_EMAIL_SUBSCRIBE', 'CAMPAIGN_ID', 'ERROR_CODE')

and INTRCTN_VAL IN ('UpdateEmailPreference', 'Y', 'N', '21312', '263', '261', '262', '48', '47', '890', '4', '1006', '500', '9999', 'ADJ-S0074-')   )

 

OR (INTRCTN_NM IN ('SOURCE_APP', 'SOURCE_PAGE', 'PREFERENCE_TYPE'))

 

OR

(

INTRCTN_NM IN ('EOB_FORMAT', 'EOB_SOURCE', 'COMPONENT_ID', 'CAMPAIGN_ID', 'ERROR_CD', 'FAIL_CODE')

)

)

and LVL2_ACCT_ID NOT IN ('TEST') --remove test accounts

group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

having INTRCTN_VAL_LIST  LIKE '%UpdateEmailPreference%' or INTRCTN_TYP_CD in ('8503', '3180', '3286')
```

Comment: Even though the result type of XMLAGG is XML, the result is limited to 64000 bytes due to an internal limit on "intermediate storage" for an aggregate function. Do you really need a result column that large?